# I am trying to edit an existing post and save it to the database but getting no reverse match error. below is my code

Tags: python, django

urls.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from posts import views

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/upvote', views.upvote, name='upvote'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/downvote', views.downvote, name='downvote'),
    url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)', views.user_post, name='user_post'),
    url(r"^delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)", views.delete_post, name="delete"),
    url(r"^edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)", views.edit_post, name="edit"),
    url(r"^save_post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)", views.save_post, name="save_post"),
]
```

views.py file. function for saving the post after editing

```
def save_post(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)

        post.title = request.POST['title']

        if request.POST['url'].startswith('http://') or request.POST['url'].startswith('https://'):
            post.url = request.POST['url']
        else:
            post.url = "http://" + request.POST['url']

        post.save()
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        return render(request,'posts/edit_post.html')
```

edit_post.html file. html file where existing data will be fetched and user can edit that

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Edit Post</h3>

      <form method="POST">

        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group form-group-md">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text" value="{{post.title}}">

            <label for="url">URL</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="url" name="url" type="text" value="{{post.url}}">
          </div>
          <a href="{% url 'posts:save_post' %}" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Save</a>
      </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[when going to save, getting following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Qx6.jpg)

Comment: The URL definition for `save_post` requires a numeric argument at the end of the URL which you aren't passing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an id in your url

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Edit Post</h3>

      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'posts:save_post' post.id %}">

        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group form-group-md">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text" value="{{post.title}}">

            <label for="url">URL</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="url" name="url" type="text" value="{{post.url}}">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-success" value="Save" />
      </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In place of anchor tag, I have placed the url into Form Action and working fine.

Comment: Yes that is the best way to use a form

Answer (score 0):

you're not passing `post` into the context on the GET request, that's why you're getting the NoReverseMatch

e.g. instead of

```
 return render(request,'posts/edit_post.html')
```

put

```
return render(request,'posts/edit_post.html', { "post": post } )
```

(of course, you'll also need to move that `post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)` above that first `if`)